# HibernateException: Could not instantiate dialect class when using HTTPS for GWT

Tags: hibernate, ssl, gwt

I don't know if this really has something to do with the fact that I let the server use SSL but this is the only change I made.

Here are the two argument lists:

**without SSL**:

> `-superDevMode -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl index.html -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher -war E:\java\mahlzeit-web\mahlzeit-web\war com.mahlzeit.web.Mahlzeit_web_server`

and here **with SSL**:

> `-superDevMode -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl index.html -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher -war E:\java\mahlzeit-web\mahlzeit-web\war com.mahlzeit.web.Mahlzeit_web_server -server :ssl com.mahlzeit.web.Mahlzeit_web_server`

If I'm running **with SSL** I'm getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate dialect class
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:148)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect cannot be cast to org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:73)
    ... 33 more
```

I really have no idea how *this* can have anything to do with SSL but there you go .. I am looking forward to getting enlightened ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `-server :ssl` then you no longer use the `AppEngineLauncher`, so class loading is different; with a parent class loader using the classpath (AppEngine **only** uses `WEB-INF/{classes,lib}`); this is what causes the `ClassCastException`.

Try removing your server dependencies from the DevMode classpath as a starting point; leaving them only in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that SuperDevMode won't work with SSL (for now); unless you reconfigure the whitelist regexp and allow mixed content in your browser.

Comment: Okay I think I'm killing me here .. All I want to do is to use a GWT project and another project of mine that is an ORM Database Backend but nothing works and now I hear that not even SSL would work. I am not sure if I should continue using GWT because it's been a real pain in the ass the last few days to get where I am now and the moment it starts to work everything has to change just because I switch to another protocl (SSL)? Is there anything I am missing out because this seems to be over my head right now ..

Comment: You said "*for now*" .. is there something coming?